# Velocity, what's the most efficient way to check if a string is empty and not null

Tags: velocity

I often have cases when a string value is absent and/or empty. Is this the best way to test this condition?

```
#if( $incentive.disclaimer && $!incentive.disclaimer != '' ) 
   $incentive.disclaimer 
#end
```

Comment: Dave, what too would you suggest?

Comment: Don't use Quiet Reference Notation $!incentive.disclaimer inside #if. It doesn't give you anything there. But you might sometimes want logical NOT !$incentive.disclaimer (not the same thing!).

Answer (score 45):

If you just want Velocity to display the value if there, or display nothing if absent, a [quiet reference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation) by itself will do the trick:

```
$!incentive.disclaimer
```

If you're wanting to explicitly test for empty, [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) can help.  First add it to your Context (reference [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#supportforstaticclasses)):

```
context.put("StringUtils", StringUtils.class);
```

Though if you're on an older version of Velocity, it may not like the class reference, so you can add an instance instead:

```
context.put("StringUtils", new StringUtils());
```

Then you can call its [isEmpty](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) method from your Velocity template:

```
#if($StringUtils.isEmpty($incentive.disclaimer))
    ## logic here...
#end
```

If you want whitespace treated as empty, there's also [isBlank](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Vadzim's answer does the job without adding an additional third party library

Comment: @Adrien Be But it makes the code kinda obscure (and it was given one month later) while this one is extremely readable. I prefer this one because of that and because this one indirectly illustrates that one can pass any class or instance into the context for use in the template (it doesn't necessarily need to be an additional third party library).

Answer (score 45):

For cases where just `$!incentive.disclaimer` doesn't fit http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/CheckingForNull suggests a short solution:

```
#if( "$!car.fuel" != "" )
```

Answer (score 16):

### You want Quiet Reference Notation: $!incentive.disclaimer

```
Bla bla $!incentive.disclaimer.
```

If **$incentive.disclaimer** is **null** or **""**, Velocity will render:

```
Bla bla .
```

Refer to the official Guide section:
https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#quiet-reference-notation

### Sometimes you do need #if

Most common case when you do want #if: your variable is just a part of a bigger piece of text and you don't want to show it if the variable is empty. Then you need this:

```
#if($incentive.disclaimer && !$incentive.disclaimer.empty) 
    Please read our incentive disclaimer:
    $incentive.disclaimer
#end
```