# can Velocity set a default value for a variable when no value found in VelocityContext?

Tags: velocity

Velocity just print the tag name if no value was found in VelocityContext, ie, $name in my template file, but there is no value for "name" in VelocityContext, so just "$name" was printed. I want Velocity to print a default value if there is no value for the variable, I just tried to extends AbstractCotnext and override internalGet() method, but the return value of internalGet() will be cast to Node object, I don't know how to create a new Node object in my internalGet() method, and also I think this way is very complex.

is there a simple way to set a default value (default value is just a string) ?

thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Not easily for all variables as far as I see, I only managed to do it for some variables specifically as follows:

Template:

```
#if ( !$somevar )
#set ( $somevar = "mycontent" )
#end

Var is: $somevar
```

Result:

```
Var is: mycontent
```

Comment: If you are a Marketo user/campaigner, the above mentioned script will not work. There should be probably other Veolocity syntax and only following will be correct:
`#if ( $somevar == "" )
#set ( $somevar = "mycontent" )
#end

Var is: $somevar
`

Answer (score 9):

Create a velocimacro in your template:

```
#macro(defaultValue $parm)  
#if (!$!parm || $!parm == "")  
i-like-will
#else  
$parm  
#end  
#end
```

And call it like this in the same template:

```
#defaultValue($name)
```

Check [Apache Velocity - Velocity User Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#velocimacros) for more info on velocimacros (and velocity in general).

Comment: why do you have \ symbols in front of your #s ?  I thought macros and if statements were defined as #macro and #if not \#if

Comment: You are correct, I'm not sure how the formatting got all messed up.  I've fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it had some special meaning I had missed :-)

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but you could also perform a check when defining a variable. I had to compress this to one line to remove excess space in the output, but here is an example from one of my projects:

```
#set ( $qlDefault = "qlinks" )
#set ( $qlClass = "#if($sharedCtaImage.getChild('path').value != '/')$qlDefault#else$qlDefault full#end" )
```

Default class is defined, then I check if another, specific value is filled in to determine if I keep the default class or append an additional class. This could also work for swapping out classes as well.

Answer (score 3):

For an empty default value, `$!name` will do. Otherwise,

`#{if}($name)${name}#{else}${default_value}#{end}`

See http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#quiet-reference-notation

Answer (score 2):

Google around for Velocity ReferenceInsertionEventHandler for a way to do it broadly.

Consider the DisplayTool's alt() method for individual cases (part of the VelocityTools project)

Comment: thanks every body every much, and allow me to ask another question: is there a way to change the variable name before render the output? for example, the variable name is userName in template file, but in VelocityContext, the key is USERNAME, I want to change variable name to capital word before render.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple things you can do short of hacking Velocity internals.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13158441/612265).