# How to use default param values in velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I am using velocity to replace string values in Java.

If my string is "${product_name} available at ${product_price}", then in velocity context, if the values corresponding to the parameters product_name and product_price are found then velocity engine will replace them. However, if not found, the placeholder will not change.

What i am trying is if there are no placeholder values, a default param value should be used. i.e. if product_name is not found in velocity context, default value provided should be used.

Is such facility provided in velocity? And if so, can anybody point me to the correct documentation.

Comment: Please, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872808/can-velocity-set-a-default-value-for-a-variable-when-no-value-found-in-velocityc. Though rather old, the answers are still valid as Velocity project is on hold.