# format LocalDateTime in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to do a date format on LocalDateTime in velocity template. But it doesn't seems to support LocalDateTime? converting LocalDateTime into timestamp is a good option for me.

Comment: Can you share some code (and some inputs and outputs) from what you've tried so we can get an idea of exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Create an extension class of DateTool and add your logic there. I've done that to extend DisplayTool.

Comment: The answer is in this link [How to select the format of $date in vm file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092372/how-to-select-the-format-of-date-in-vm-file)