# Velocity - Checking for whitespaces in a string and return those strings

Tags: whitespace, velocity

We often have the situation, that string values start with a whitespace. How can I check and return all strings which start with a whitespace?

I found a similar question: [Velocity, what's the most efficient way to check if a string is empty and not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158441/velocity-whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-empty-and-not-nu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But I don't know how to exactly do it, as I have never done anything with Velocity before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you can call Java methods on Velocity references. So nothing stops you from doing:

```
#foreach($str in $myStrings)
  #if($str.startsWith(' '))
    ## do something with $str
  #end
#end
```